# Empty result after execute first observable subscribe inside foreach to end?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3

I’m using ionic 3, angular 5,
I’m not sure what’s wrong with my code, I have the result always empty of observable inside foreach. Here’s my code:

```
articlepanier : Article[] = [];
    this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(token => {
      let isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(token);
      if(!isExpired){  
        //foreach loop 
        this.cart.forEach((element, index) => {
        var article = new Article();
        article.artid = element.artid;
        article.artcode = element.artcode;
        //value of the sales unit quantity
        article.plvqteuv = element.amount;
        
        let data = {
            pricode: this.pricode,
            artcode: element.artcode
        };

        //use observable to return stock available in the database  
        //and change the value of the article.plvqtyisvalid by false value at each line 
        //if the quantity entered exceeds the quantity available
        this.cardProvider.stockbyarticle(data).subscribe((res: any) => {
          if( res.quantity < element.amount ){
            //change boolean status quantity is valid
            article.plvqtyisvalid = false;
          }
          
          //method changes the contents of array
          this.articlepanier.splice(index, 0, article);
          
            console.log(this.articlepanier);
        });
            
    });

    //Here outside of foreach, I want the result of array after executing foreach (this.articlepanier) to be used in a if condition 
    //But articlepanier is always empty

    if(this.articlepanier.filter(c =>(c.plvqtyisvalid  == true).length > 0){
        //recording the cart in database 
    }
  
  });
```

I want the result of observable inside foreach but this.articlepanier is always empty, her outside foreach

Comment: is it entering inside `stockbyarticle` ? have you check it with console logs ? that will help you where exactly it's stuck or come out from `forEach`

Comment: stockbyarticle  is a function in provider. Yep, I have already checked in console, but the return is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues here

1. You're subscribing inside a `forEach`. So each element would constitute an individual subscription. Instead you could use RxJS functions like `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `zip` to subscribe to multiple observables in parallel.
2. You're trying to access the asynchronous variable `articlepanier` synchronously. It isn't adjusted yet by the time you're trying to access it outside the subscription. You need to make the entire stream reactive using RxJS operators like `switchMap`.

Try the following

```js
import { from, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY)).pipe(
  filter(token => !(helper.isTokenExpired(token))),
  switchMap(_ => {
    return forkJoin(this.cart.map((element, index) => {
      const article = new Article();
      article.artid = element.artid;
      article.artcode = element.artcode;
      article.plvqteuv = element.amount; //value of the sales unit quantity
      let data = {
        pricode: this.pricode,
        artcode: element.artcode
      };
      return this.cardProvider.stockbyarticle(data).pipe(
        tap((res: any) => {
          if (res.quantity < element.amount) { // change boolean status quantity is valid
            article.plvqtyisvalid = false;
          }
          this.articlepanier.splice(index, 0, article); // method changes the contents of array
          console.log(this.articlepanier);
        })
      )
    }))
  })
).subscribe(
  res => {
    if (this.articlepanier.filter(c => (c.plvqtyisvalid == true).length > 0)) {
      // recording the card in database 
    }
  }
);
```

Note I'm using RxJS `from` function to convert the Promise returned from `this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY)` function to an observable. It's better to either work with Promises or Observables and not combine them. I'm also using RxJS `filter` operator to check if the token is still valid.

Comment: Thanks, you help me a lot! These explanations make me feel good, I will try this!

Comment: Thank you Sir, that's the solution